# Disclosure Indicator doesn't call seque while Detail Disclosure does

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I have an interesting problem.  I'd like to have detail screen pop up when people click on the arrow in the Table View.  The cells are dynamic.

When I select Disclosure Indicator - I do not get the segue called and and I don't get accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath called either.  When I change it to Detail Disclosure everything works just fine.

Any guesses to what I can do to make the disclosure indicator act just like the detail disclosure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclosure indicators are not buttons and therefore do not cause the `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` delegate method to fire, while a detail disclosure *is* a button and therefore does fire that method.

The best you can hope to do, I imagine, is to add a `UIButton` to your table view cell and give it an image that very closely resembles the default table view disclosure indicator. This is kind of a hacky solution though, so I would discourage you from actually doing this.

Comment: what's the best practice for accomplishing the "click on the arrow" like in Mint and other apps?

Comment: @mikebz As far as I can tell, there is no "click on the arrow" functionality in the Mint app. It seems that tapping on any of the disclosure arrows just does the same thing as tapping the cell itself, which probably calls `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to perform segues or do other things. So basically the best practice is to not have disclosure indicators be tappable and instead utilize the cell selection mechanisms, and if you want to provide a separate detail view for an item then use the detail disclosure accessory type.