# Call segue with Disclousure indicator won't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, segue

My question is very similar to this:

[Disclosure Indicator doesn't call seque while Detail Disclosure does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103040/disclosure-indicator-doesnt-call-seque-while-detail-disclosure-does)

But is a bit different.

The same is happening to me. I have a dynamic table view which loads some rows at viewLoad.

So I set the segue from the Cell to a new View which will show some details of the item. I also set the Segue to Push.

When I do that, the Cell automatically sets its Accessory to Detail Indicator (So the blue info button appears) This works fine, I click on the info button and it loads the new view. **But I do not want that, I want the Cell to have a Disclousure indicator (the arrow) and whenever you click on the entire row, just Push the new view.** I did this on an Static Table View and it worked fine, but I can't make it work with a Dynamic Table. Nothing happens when I click, just the animation of the tap and nothing else.

Comment: It sounds like your segue is an "accessory Action" segue rather than a "Selection" segue. You said you got the blue detail disclosure button when you made the segue. What did you do next? Did you set the cell's accessory to none to get rid of the button?

Comment: What do you mean with "is an accessory Action segue rather than a Selection segue"? . When the blue detail disclosure button appeared, I changed the Accesory to Disclosure Indicator. So that the arrow appears. Isn't this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not ok to change an accessory action segue to a selection one by setting the accessory to none -- that doesn't change the segue type. The fact that you got the blue button when you made the segue means you chose an "Accessory Action" segue. When you drag from the cell to the next controller and let go, you get a menu of choices that's divided into two sections. The top ones are Selection segues, and the bottom set are Accessory Action segues. You need to delete your segue and remake it, being sure to choose from the Selection segue choices.

Comment: Thanks !! Can't believe have been dealing with this for almost half an hour